# rake routes shows routes.. but I got ActionController::RoutingError(no route error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rake routes
[image]

this is my routes file
[image]

but when I make request '/', I got error

```
F, [2020-02-12T04:57:06.400949 #21830] FATAL -- : [eac71eea-131f-4edc-8c7f-7681d02c6824] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
```

it's working in my local.

I set :server_mode in secrets.yml, and It worked.
but, in production, it's not working.

I had to make routes in routes.rb not admin_routes.rb.

What should I do?

Comment: The first image was `RAILS_ENV=production rake routes` on the server? Could you try to restart puma/unicron, and then check if it works.

Comment: Does it show routes on server console? I don't think it will if it is not working in that specific environment. Also double check the server_mode secret and maybe put a puts/Logger line to check if that line is actually working.

Comment: You may have root i.e. `'/'` defined for development there and not for production. Have you checked that?